# How to find the recurrence formula for the number of ways of clustering given size n and number of clusters to be k?

Tags: algorithm

Here I'm kinda stuck with this quiz problem. It asks for the recurrence function for number of ways that a set of n points can be clustered into k non-empty clusters.

My initial thought is that it should be S(n,k) = nS(n, k-1) since for every increase in the number of clusters by one, there should be n more ways to add a cluster to existing clusters of k-1 in size.

The picture attached is the actual question. Thanks a lot!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gneub.png)

Comment: Does the order of clusters matter? That is, if a have 2 points and two clusters, is there 1 or 2 ways?

Comment: @kraskevich it's given (in the image) that S(n, n) = 1, so the clusters are identified but the points are not.

Answer (score 3):

You can get k non-empty clusters, containing n objects:

by adding n-th object to any existing cluster (there are k of them, so `k*S(n-1,k)` variants)

or making new cluster containing single n-th object in addition to (k-1) existing clusters (`S(n-1,k-1)` variants)